# Help with evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

As part of a problem, I'm stuck evaluating the following integral

$$ \int_0^\pi \sin\left(\left|\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right|\right) \sin (2y)~dy.$$  I seek assistance in evaluating it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any interval defined for x and y?

Comment: no Ram. there is no interval.

Comment: I mean is there any relation between x and y, I hope x is like $ 0 \le x \le \pi$ then you can reduce into two intervals, $ sin(x/2 - y/2)$ in $0 \le y \le x$ and $ sin(y/2 - x/2)$ in $x < y \le \pi$

Comment: @Ram: yes $0\le x \le \pi$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, break it into two pieces, one from $0$ to $x$, the other from $x$ to $\pi$. This way, you can write an equivalent integral without absolute value signs.

Then can you do $\int\sin(a-by)\sin(cy)\,dy$? It might help to remember there's a trig identity for $\sin A\sin B$.

Comment: Would this work: $$\int_0^x \sin(x-y)\sin(2y)-\int_x^\pi sin(x-y)\sin(2y) dy?$$

Comment: It appears you've misplaced the $2$s in the denominators but, aside from that, it looks like what I had in mind.